# d3.js - how to update chart data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

Another step in my journey to learn D3.js...

I've got a simple reusable chart I'm calling a 'cluster chart', and I'm trying to get my head around simply updating some values without adding or subtracting any elements.

There is a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rolfsf/8bXAN/

The chart script looks like this:

```
    function clusterChart() {
    var width = 500,
        radiusAll = 90,
        maxRadius = radiusAll - 5,
        padding = 8, 
        height = 3 * (radiusAll*2 + padding),
        startAngle = Math.PI / 2,
        val = function(d) { return d; },
        onTotalMouseOver = null,
        onTotalClick = null,
        onClusterMouseOver = null,
        onClusterClick = null;

    function chart(selection) {
        selection.each(function(data) {

            var cx = width / 2,
                cy = height / 2,
                stepAngle = 2 * Math.PI / data.Clusters.length,
                outerRadius = 2*radiusAll + padding;


            //  Remove svg, if already exist
            d3.select(this).select('svg').remove();

            //cluster radius range and scale
            var r = d3.scale.linear()
                        .domain([0, d3.max(data.Clusters, function(d){return d[1];})])
                        .range([50, maxRadius]);

            //  Add svg element
            var svg = d3.select(this).append('svg')
                .attr('class', 'cluster-chart')
                .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height )
                .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMin meet")
                .attr('width', width)
                .attr('height', height);

            //  Total group value
            var totalCluster = svg.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'total-cluster');

            totalCluster.append('circle')
                .attr('cx', cx)
                .attr('cy', cy)
                .attr('r', radiusAll)
                .on('mouseover', onTotalMouseOver)
                .on('click', onTotalClick);

            totalCluster.append('text')
                .attr('class', 'value')
                .attr('x', cx)
                .attr('y', cy + 4)
                .text(val(data.Value));

            totalCluster.append('text')
                .attr('class', 'group-name')
                .attr('x', cx)
                .attr('y', cy + 16)
                .text(val(data.Name));

            //  Clusters values
            var cluster =  svg.selectAll('g.cluster')
                .data(data.Clusters)
                .enter().append('g')
                .attr('class', function(d, i) { 
                    if(d[1] === 0){ return 'cluster empty'}
                    else {return 'cluster'}
                });

            cluster.append('circle')
                .attr('cx', function(d, i) { return cx + Math.cos(startAngle + stepAngle * i) * outerRadius; })
                .attr('cy', function(d, i) { return cy + Math.sin(startAngle + stepAngle * i) * outerRadius; })
                .attr("r", function (d, i) { return r(d[1]); })
                .on('mouseover', function(d, i, j) {
                    //do something
                    if (onClusterMouseOver != null) onClusterMouseOver(d, i, j);
                })
                .on('mouseout', function() {
                    //do something
                })
                .on('click', function(d, i){ onClusterClick(d); });  

            cluster.append('text')
                .attr('class', 'value')
                .attr('x', function(d, i) { return cx + Math.cos(startAngle + stepAngle * i) * outerRadius; })
                .attr('y', function(d, i) { return cy + Math.sin(startAngle + stepAngle * i) * outerRadius - 4; })
                .text(function(d) { return val(d[1]); });

            cluster.append('text')
                .attr('class', 'group-name')
                .attr('x', function(d, i) { return cx + Math.cos(startAngle + stepAngle * i) * outerRadius; })
                .attr('y', function(d, i) { return cy + Math.sin(startAngle + stepAngle * i) * outerRadius + 16; })
                .text(function(d) { return val(d[0]); });

            $(window).resize(function() {
              var w = $('.cluster-chart').width(); //make this more generic
              svg.attr("width", w);
              svg.attr("height", w * height / width);
            });

        });


    }


    chart.width = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return width;
        width = _;
        return chart;
    };

    chart.height = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return height;
        height = _;
        return chart;
    };

    chart.val = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return val;
        val = _;
        return chart;
    };

    chart.onClusterClick = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return onClusterClick;
        onClusterClick = _;
        return chart;
    };

    return chart;
 }
```

and I call the chart like so:

```
d3.select('#clusters')
.datum({
    Name: 'Total Widgets',
    Value: 224,
    Clusters: [
        ['Other', 45],
        ['FooBars', 30],
        ['Foos', 50],
        ['Bars', 124],
        ['BarFoos', 0]
    ]
})
.call( clusterChart() );
```

Ultimately, the data will come from a json file, but for now it's there in the function.

Let's say I want to update the values when the #doSomething button is clicked, and the updated data looks like this:

```
.datum({
    Name: 'Total Widgets',
    Value: 150,
    Clusters: [
        ['Other', 25],
        ['FooBars', 25],
        ['Foos', 25],
        ['Bars', 75],
        ['BarFoos', 0]
    ]
})
```

**How do I update that data, with a nice transition as the radii change?**

**UPDATE:** Ok, I realize that one line pretty much wipes out my ability to 'update' the chart.

```
//  Remove svg, if already exist
d3.select(this).select('svg').remove();
```

instead, I should do something like:

```
//  Add svg element
var svg = d3.select(this).selectAll('svg')
```

so I don't erase the entire chart. But even with that, I don't get how to update with new data.

Any clues?

Comment: In principle, all you have to do is bind the new data, update the scale for the radii and run the code to set the radius based on the bound data.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thanks - yes, in principle. My knowledge of d3 still has large gaps. I don't really understand how to get just the part of the chart code I want without redrawing the whole chart. Will study the lifecycle events demo for clues